# A simple multi-step form in Vue.js. Adding classes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

This is a simple multi-step form written in Vue.js. **How to modify the code to add the "error" class to "input text" in case of an error.** I would be very grateful for your help.

P.S

The question should be short, but stackoverflow required more text in my question. The length of the question must be proportional to the amount of code :)

Regards, Konrad

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Website</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.7.14"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <form id="app">
        <span v-for="e in errors">{{ e }}</span>
        <section v-if="step == 1">
          <h3>Step 1</h3>
          <input v-model="form.name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Type your name">
        </section>

        <section v-if="step == 2">
          <h3>Step 2</h3>
            <input v-model="form.phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Type your phone number">
            <input v-model="form.email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Type your email">          
        </section>

        <section v-if="step == 3">
          <h3>Step 3</h3>
            <textarea v-model="form.message" placeholder="Type message"></textarea>          
        </section>
        <button v-if="step != 1" @click.prevent="prevStep" >Prev Step</button>
        <button v-if="step != totalsteps" @click.prevent="nextStep" >Next Step</button>

      </form>
    </main>

  <script>
    
    const App = new Vue({

      el:"#app",

        data: {

          step: 1,
          totalsteps: 3,
          errors: [],

          form: {
            name: null,
            email: null,
            phone: null,
            message: null
          }

        },

      methods: {

        nextStep:function(){

          if(this.step == 1)
          {
            if(!this.form.name)
            {
              this.errors = 'Type your name'
              return false;
            }
          }

          if(this.step == 2)
          {
            if(!this.form.phone)
            {
              this.errors = 'Type your phone';
              return false;
            }
            if(!this.form.email)
            {
              this.errors = 'Type your email'
              return false;
            }
          }

          this.errors = null;

          this.step++;

        },

        prevStep:function(){

          this.step--;

        }

      }

    });

  </script>

  <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style

Comment: @bassxzero Unfortunately I can't do this :( I'm a newbie. I wrote this piece of code based on the tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind classes like this:

```js
<div :class="{ 'has-error': e }"></div>
```

Or if you want to add multiple classes you can do this instead:

```js
<div :class="['some-other-class', { 'has-error': e }]"></div>
```

‌

The updated code will be something like below:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        step: 1,
        totalSteps: 3,
        errors: {
          name: undefined,
          phone: undefined,
          email: undefined,
        },
        form: {
          name: null,
          email: null,
          phone: null,
          message: null,
        },
      };
    },

    methods: {
      nextStep() {
        this.errors = {
          name: undefined,
          phone: undefined,
          email: undefined,
        };

        if (this.step == 1) {
          if (!this.form.name) {
            this.errors.name = "Type your name";
            return false;
          }
        }

        if (this.step == 2) {
          if (!this.form.phone) {
            this.errors.phone = "Type your phone";
            return false;
          }

          if (!this.form.email) {
            this.errors.email = "Type your email";
            return false;
          }
        }

        this.step++;
      },

      prevStep() {
        this.step--;
      },
    },
  };
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <form id="app">
      <span v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</span>

      <section v-if="step == 1">
        <h3>Step 1</h3>
        <input
          v-model="form.name"
          type="text"
          name="name"
          placeholder="Type your name"
          :class="{'has-error': errors.name}"
        />
      </section>

      <section v-if="step == 2">
        <h3>Step 2</h3>
        <input
          v-model="form.phone"
          type="tel"
          name="phone"
          placeholder="Type your phone number"
          :class="{'has-error': errors.phone}"
        />
        <input
          v-model="form.email"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Type your email"
          :class="{'has-error': errors.email}"
        />
      </section>

      <section v-if="step == 3">
        <h3>Step 3</h3>
        <textarea v-model="form.message" placeholder="Type message"></textarea>
      </section>

      <button v-if="step != 1" @click.prevent="prevStep">Prev Step</button>
      <button v-if="step != totalSteps" @click.prevent="nextStep">
        Next Step
      </button>
    </form>
  </main>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .has-error {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please improve my code? I'm a newbie. I wrote this piece of code based on the tutorial :)

Comment: Yes, sure, I'll edit my answer in a few bit ...

Comment: Not working :( https://jsfiddle.net/mousebucks/h3dp185c/

Comment: Use this: https://playcode.io/vue

Comment: Or this one: https://jsfiddle.net/2pfy4mjk

Comment: @Mousebucks the reason your jsfiddle doesn't work is because it's written as a Vue component (.vue file), but it's a javascript/HTML playground.  For Vue to work you need to include the Vue library CDN (global build) and write the Vue app using the [instructions](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start#using-the-global-build) for global build, which is what Sttatusx did in his jsfiddle.  The **answer code** _would_ work in an actual .vue file.